# Send reference letters from mathjobs to other positions

Tags: mathematics, career-path, job-search, recommendation-letter

I am currently applying to several postdoc positions. My referees have uploaded their reference letters to Mathjobs, but I'm also applying to some positions out of Mathjobs. In order to avoid disturbing my referees again and again:

*Question*: Is there a way to send a reference letter uploaded on Mathjobs to a position out of Mathjobs?

Comment: Why don't you contact Mathjobs directly?

Comment: @user4050: Done!

Comment: You just have to disturb them. It helps to remember that someone had to write letters for your referees, in order to get them where they are today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

As suggested by user4050, I contacted Mathjobs directly and they answered the following:

> Hello Sebastien,
>
> Applicants do not have access to the letters uploaded into MathJobs.
>   There is some import capability between MathJobs and
>   AcademicJobsOnline, but you do not have the ability to export your
>   letters otherwise.
>
> If you need anything else, please let me know.
>
> Regards,
>
> Kim Kuda
>   Senior Program Coordinator